# Where can I find a video component or library for C#?

Tags: c#, video, components

Is there a video library that will enable me to do basic functionality with videos such as splitting a video into two, capturing a frame from a video, converting video between different formats, etc.?

Comment: checkout [ffmpeg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/).

Comment: No changes since 2008, isn't this dead?

Comment: @alxandr the last time I looked at it, which was ~6 months ago, I couldn't get it to work.  SO yeah, I think its dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what type of client technology are you using ? Silverlight has a lot of really great video functionality but you need to be comfortable with XAML. 
[Silverlight Video Player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg981349)

Comment: I am comfortable with xaml because I work with wpf applications. I've never worked with silverlight that's why I was hoping to create in in wpf. But I heard that wpf applications are similar to silverlight applications therefore I might give it a try

Comment: if you know XAML you know silverlight... I jump between the two frequently and can hardly tell the difference.

Comment: so I will use silverlight then. What classes should I use? do I need to add any references?

Comment: do all silver-light applications need to run in a browser?

Comment: no silverlight apps can run OOB(Out Of Browser) with no code changes. I think its called a SLOOB.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is great for playing video... not so great for doing things like transcoding.  Expression Encoder (SDK) does some things easily, but beyond that you really need to use unmanaged code to do anything sophisticated.  Intel IPP, OpenCV, and DirectShow are the usual suspects none of which are going to be plug and play.